# How to fetch full content from RSS url?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I’m developing an RSS fetcher API which can fetch the full RSS content from RSS URL. I have searched a lot but I am unable to make it work. Now my API gets only short content (description) from RSS feed URL.

The code used by me:

```
 $rss = fetch_feed($entry->rss_link);
    $number_of_post=2;
    $iCount=0;
    foreach ($rss->get_items() as $item)
    {
        $content= $item->get_description();
        if($entry->remove_link){
           $content=strip_tags($content, '<p><div><i><b><u><img>');
        }
        $iCount++;
        $sfp_page = array(
            'post_title' => $item->get_title(),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_content' =>$content,
            'post_type' => 'sfp_forum',
            'post_author' => $entry->author_id,
            'post_date' => current_time('mysql')
        );
        $rss_id = wp_insert_post($sfp_page);

    }
```

`$content` doesn’t have the full content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the feed you are accessing have full content posts in it?

Comment: No it have only the short content ...  here is the e.g. http://feeds.feedburner.com/learnhack

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do something like the following because you are overwriting your `$content` on each iteration so you only get the last item.

```
$rss = fetch_feed($entry->rss_link);
$number_of_post=2;
$iCount=0;
$content = array();
foreach ($rss->get_items() as $item){
    $content[$iCount] = $item->get_description();
    if($entry->remove_link){
       $content[$iCount] = strip_tags($content[$iCount], '<p><div><i><b><u><img>');
    }
    $iCount++;
}
var_dump($content);
```